# How do I set the ID of a Clickable Span?

Tags: java, android, clickable, spannablestring

What I want to do is this:

1. I have a string: "A String"
2. I want to make "A" and "String" independently clickable.
3. I want to assign each an ID so that when they are clicked, I can use the ID to look up for the individual string's meaning in my database (the strings are in Arabic actually).

And BTW, I've tried to catch one clickablespan's ID (using getID method) and it turned out to be just a random number (which is 2131558509).

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of `ClickableSpan`. Put your identifiers in the subclass. Then, use the subclass when adding the spans to your `Spannable`.

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you.